# Native query as variable

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way to pass a native query as a variable?

I want to use something like that

```
@Component
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, long>{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = query) 
    List<Sapf> find(String query);
}
```

Comment: If you're building that query dynamically, then no, it's not possible. You need to use a custom repository implementation and pass your query to the entity manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom repository to solve your problem. According to [the Spring Data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) you start with an interface:

```
public interface MyRepositoryCustom {
    List<Sapf> find(String query);
}
```

Then you need to implement it. You need to inject the entity manager so you can execute the native query:

```
public class MyRepositoryCustomImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "yourPersistenceUnitName")
    private EntityManager em;

    List<Sapf> find(String query) {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(query, Sapf.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Finally, you extend the created interface in your Spring Data Repository and the rest is done by the framework.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, long>, MyRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Depending on your Spring configuration, your custom implementation should be used automatically. If not, check out the documentation to adjust you settings.

Comment: The name of your persistence unit that you have in your Spring configuration. If you have only one persistence unit in you application, you can omit this parameter.

Comment: I got error "No property find found for type Sapf!" when I extends MyRepository. When I use MyRepositoryCustomImpl as a @Component and inject it to other class the methon fine(String query) it works fine.

Comment: Is the Sapf class an entity? If not then you'll need to define a custom mapping using @SqlResultSetMapping

Comment: Yes, Sapf class is entity

Comment: The problem might be connected with the fact that methods started with `find` are treated specially by Spring Data. Try renaming the method `find` to something else and see if it helps.

Comment: is the above implementation possible for JPA query instead of Native Query?